# Как создать исключение конкретной ошибки ftplib?

Tags: python, исключения, ftp, обработка-ошибок

К примеру есть ошибка "ftplib.error_perm: 530 User cannot log in.". Как создать исключение по коду ошибки?
Нужно чтобы программа выводила пользователю в чем конкретно ошибка, при этом выполнение не останавливалось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так.

```
try:
    ftp = FTP('adress', 'user', 'password')
except error_perm as err:   # представляем ошибку как переменную err
    if str(err) == "530 User cannot log in.":   # преобразуем ошибку в строковый тип
        print("Invalid username or password")
    else:
        print(err)
```

Answer (score 3):

Похоже код 530 может использоваться для различных сообщений:

```
In [263]: ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.hornet.org')

In [264]: ftp.login('aaa', 'user@example.com')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error_perm                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
error_perm: 530 This FTP server is anonymous only.
```

поэтому можно проверять само сообщение об ошибке:

```
try:
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.hornet.org')
    ftp.login('aaa', 'user@example.com')
except ftplib.error_perm as exc:
    if str(exc) == "530 User cannot log in.":
        print("Здесь обрабатываем ошибку ...")
    else:
        raise
```

рабочий пример:

```
In [265]: try:
     ...:     ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.hornet.org')
     ...:     ftp.login('aaa', 'user@example.com')
     ...: except ftplib.error_perm as exc:
     ...:     if str(exc) == "530 This FTP server is anonymous only.":
     ...:         print("Здесь обрабатываем ошибку ...")
     ...:     else:
     ...:         raise
     ...: 
Здесь обрабатываем ошибку ...
```